# Cannot update rows within table using select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a column within a table from which I would like to populate the table with data retrieved from another select statement.

This is the statement I am trying to use to populate that one column:

```
update cc_file
set sd_file_name = (select c1.name sd_file_name
                    from cc_file f, cvs3 c1 
                    where f.sd_file_id = c1.file_id 
                     and (c1.file_id, c1.type) in (select file_id, 
                                                          max(type) 
                                                   from cvs3 
                                                   where type1='PP' 
                                                     and type2='XHMTML' 
                                                   group by file_id)
```

When I run this statement in Oracle it shows this error `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

Please can someone let me know how I can do this so the column is updated.

Thanks

Comment: select c1.name sd_file_name there is some problem you have not `c1` object on any table please check it

Comment: The problem is that your select statement is returning multiple rows, but you can only have one value in an assignment like this. You need to fix the select statement so that it returns the one file name that you want to use.

Also, this form of update statement will set xml_file_name to the same value in all rows of the table, is that what you want? I suspect what you really want is for each row to get xml_file_name corresponding to its existing xml_file_id, is that it?

Comment: I have updated the c1 object. Yes @Barmar you are correct this is what I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes this is definately the correct statement

Comment: @Ricky, when you made that edit you lost the `update` that used to be at the beginning.

Comment: "Cannot update rows ... using `SELECT` statement" Is some some newfangled NoSQL fad where read only operations can have side effects and the side effects are eventually consistent?

Comment: You need to make sure the sub-select returns **exactly** one row, just as the error message tells you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok thanks, so I cannot change the statement so it populates the table with all the data in one go. Do I need to make a seperate statement for each row?

Comment: What is the primary key of the `cc_file` table? Does it match to any columns returned by your SELECT statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name within the cc_file table I have a column called File, language and sd_file_id. These match the cvs3 table that has File, language and file_id. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
update cc_file 
  set xml_file_name = (select c1.name sd_file_name
                         from cvs3 c
                         where f.sd_file_id = cc_file.file_id and 
                               (c.file_id, c.type) in (select file_id, max(type)
                                                         from cvs3
                                                         where type1='PP' and 
                                                               type2='XHMTML'
                                                         group by file_id ))
```

Comment: It's fine now I added statements at the end to link it to the other tables and also added distinct and it worked thanks.